# Open Port 3000 in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an instance and I have tried to open port 3000 (from VPC network / Firewall Rules) so that it is visible (following the steps indicated in the documentation). However, I couldn't do it.

The platform is a Debian 9.

Answer (score 0):

By default all ports in GCP are open ([with the exception of 25](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/)).

While firewall rules are defined at the network level, connections are allowed or denied on a per-instance basis.

Every network has two implied firewall rules which permit outgoing connections and block incoming connections. Firewall rules that you create can override these implied rules.

I would double check my firewall rules in the subnet where your instance is, check my screenshot where I'm allowing all traffic to all ports.

[image]

If you already have a similar configuation then I would test if you are not blocking the traffic inside the OS, try doing a nmap from your local machine

```
nmap -p 3000 EXTERNAL-IP
```

If the output is closed/filtered then you have a firewall blocking the traffic.

Finally make sure you have an application listening into that port

Comment: I will try that way.